# Rails - Error CSS styles

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, ruby, view

New to rails, and am experimenting with changing default layouts.

It seems that the `.field_with_errors` class is always being added to my forms, when a field causes a validation error. The default scaffold CSS defined `field_with_errors` as:

```
.field_with_errors {
  padding: 2px;
  background-color: red;
  display: table;
}
```

My question is: Why even use this `.field_with_errors`? Where is it even coming from? Same with a div with ID of `notice` to print success messages. Where is this coming from?... From my research both of these coming somewhere from `ActionView::Helpers`.

But what if I wanted to use my own custom styles for these? Do I have to write my own `.fields_with_errors` and `notice` classes in my application.css.scss file? I tried this and it works... But why do I have to jail myself to those class names? What if I wanted to call them something else? Can I do this?

Secondly, let's say I have my own custom CSS classes now (assuming it's possible -- which I hope it is)... What if I wanted to apply a bootstrap style to them?  For example, bootstrap would use `<div class="alert alert-success">` where Rails' scaffold would default to using `<div id="#notice">`... How can I make such changes in the most elegant way without simply making my own style with the same CSS code as Twitter's `alert alert-success`.... Isn't there a way in SASS (or through Rails somehow) to say, *Success messages are printed with XYZ style and error fields are printed with ABC style*... Like maybe in some config file?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

**Can I do this?** yes.

The extra code is being added by `ActionView::Base.field_error_proc`. If you want to call something else and you're not using `field_with_errors` to style your form, You should override it in `config/application.rb`

```
config.action_view.field_error_proc = Proc.new { |html_tag, instance| 
     "<div class='your class'>#{html_tag}</div>".html_safe 
}
```

Restart your server

---

**Secondly**, If you want to apply a bootstrap style to them, You can save your selection style on `application_helper.rb`

```
module ApplicationHelper
 def flash_class(level)
     case level
     when :notice then "alert alert-info"
     when :success then "alert alert-success"
     when :error then "alert alert-error"
     when :alert then "alert alert-error"
     end
 end
end
```

create file `layouts/_flash_message.html.erb` and paste this :

```
<div>
  <% flash.each do |key, value| %>
    <div class="<%= flash_class(key) %> fade in">
      <a href="#" data-dismiss="alert" class="close">×</a>
      <%= value %>
    </div>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

and to call the flash you just render in view

```
<%= render 'layouts/flash_messages' %>
```

**Example**

On `accounts_controller.rb` create action

```
  def create
  @account = Account.new(params[:account])
  if @account.save
     # using :success if @account.save
     flash[:success] = "Success."
     redirect_to accounts_url
  else
    flash[:alert] = "Failed."
    render :new
  end
  end
```

Put on top of `accounts/index.html.erb` and on top of form in `accounts/_form.html.erb`

```
  <%= render 'layouts/flash_messages' %>
```

Result on index :

```
<div class="alert alert-success">
   <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">×</button>
   Success.
</div>
```

Result on form :

```
 <div class="alert alert-error">
     <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">×</button>
     Failed.
 </div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response. I'm trying the first part to override the style, but it doesn't seem to work. I put the code within my application.rb file exactly as you have it, and changed the class to my custom class. When I render the page again, it's still showing `field_with_errors` as the error class name rather than the custom class that I inserted `error_fields`

Comment: on that note... what is the correct practice as far as overriding these default styles go? For example, I imagine the default layout does not suffice for anyone wanting good UI :-) So how do people normally override it? Does standard practice say to override the proc? Or do people just keep `.fields_with_errors` as the class and write their on CSS for it?

Comment: Have you restart server after you add them to `application.rb` ?

Comment: In one situation I rewrote ActionView::Base.field_error_proc (there is a rails cast on it). If you want to modify it to suit your taste, for example : you can using a little nokogiri, you changed the proc to add the error messages to the input/textarea element's data-error attribute instead of wrapping them in an error div.

Comment: There are many more ways to do it all. Ref : [Customize Field Error](http://railscasts.com/episodes/39-customize-field-error) , [error_messages_for](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/ActiveRecordHelper/error_messages_for), [Configuring Action View](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html)

Answer (score 0):

@anonymousxxx answer seems to be correct in my opinion.

I would recommend you to use the twitter-bootstrap-rails gem (https://github.com/seyhunak/twitter-bootstrap-rails) for your css. check out the readme on github, this gem is really convenient.